# UWP check the current page for name or instance

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp

In my UWP app I am launching from protocol or toast. In the onactivated method I want to check whether the apps' mainview is open or which page it is showing. All from the App.xaml.cs

I wanna do something like:

```
If Mainpage is not showing --> Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

or

```
If main window is not open since i am coming from protocol or toast launch
open frame and navigate to mainpage.
```

not sure how to go about it.

Comment: The best way is to keep track of this yourself, in order to avoid limbo states where the page is showing but not yet initialized. But if you really don't want to keep track of your own app state, you can ask `Frame.Content.GetType()`.

Comment: you're a life saver. you should post it as an answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: Go ahead and post the answer yourself and accept it. (This is allowed.)

Comment: I know but you should be getting it. ñ=

Comment: I give you permission. I don't need the imaginary internet points. You can give as much detail in the answer as you feel necessary to answer the question.

Comment: It's not that. it's just the only way i can thank for your time somehow. So thanks again, and I'm grateful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I'm checking for

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

if (frame != null)
{
    Type whatpageisit = frame.SourcePageType;
    // handle this page type
}
else
{
    // do what you need to in case window not open
}
```