# create Page from Type in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I saw this
[UWP check the current page for name or instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503078/uwp-check-the-current-page-for-name-or-instance)
 question on stackoverflow. It mentions I can get the page's Type by `currentFrame.SourcePageType`. my question is: once I have the type of the page active in the current `Frame`, how can I access elements of that page, e.g. a TextBox?

Comment: You want to access an internal member from outside of a page, without a reference to that page (now you have got only a type)... while this is possible, I feel that you may be doing in a wrong way. Nowadays we use patterns like MVVM so we don’t need to manipulate a control from C# code, we just have to deal with the model/viewmodel that the view is bound to.

Comment: Unless m, you do have a good reason you need this kind of access.

Comment: Don't worry, @7gegenTheben, you can do what you want in UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but that's cool. Do it like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(null, PageType.ToString());
```

> Once instantiated, a page cannot be added to the `Frame`, so that's a thing you should remember if it's in the back of our mind to nav to an instance.

To access controls, I think you mean, you will need to make them public by doing this: `<Control x:Name="MyControl" x:FieldModifier="Public" />` The `x:ModifyField` directive is the key.

> More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute

#### Opps, there's this, too

You aren't wanting to instantiate the type, which is what I first thought you wanted to do, now I see you just want to access the `Page` currently visible in the `Frame`, that's *so* much easier.

```
var p = _frame.Content as Page;
p.MyControl.Text = "Hello world";
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I left the first part, the wrong part, of the answer just because it's interesting.